# Hosted Blazor WASM with Identity Server and external login isn't working in production environment

Tags: ssl-certificate, blazor, identity, webassembly, hosted

I’ve been trying to follow the same guide that pertains to hosting on Azure, but instead self hosting with Kestrel. [This](https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/19572) is similar, but uses Azure.  Everything works fine until I add a valid ssl site certificate, then the external login api calls are not found according to the code in App.razor. It returns “nothing found at this location“. Curiously, if I ctrl + F5 refresh it continues to the verify email page like it should have. All I have to do is remove the site cert, or change to self-signed (as long as the site cert isn’t trusted) then the return from external login provider works correctly. Is there documentation for Kestrel as the host instead of Azure? I have also tried behind Nginx proxy but that doesn't work either. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution here...

https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/25430

I think this needs to be better documented in these pages:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio

and

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/facebook-logins?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Comment: This is the comment from your first link that had the code I needed to add: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/25430#issuecomment-760911529